# What is the benefit of using psycopg2 with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I understand that psycopg2 is more of a DB driver, and SQLAlchemy is an ORM.

As the latest SQLAlchemy already supports postgreSQL dialect and connection pools, what are the benefits of using psycopg2 (postgresql+psycopg2) or its connection pool over SQLAlchemy's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the sqlalchemy docs, specifically the diagram [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/intro.html#id1).

In that diagram, SQLAlchemy's support for PostgreSQL lies in the core segment, notably in the dialect box. psycopg2 is the DBAPI box below it. SQLAlchemy does not duplicate what psycopg2 does, but it does know how to talk to psycopg2 and it knows what native features of PostgreSQL it can instruct psycopg2 to use.

Comment: thank you, your answer and the diagram made things crystal clear. May I also ask, in your experience, since both offer connection pool, which one is recommended ? Should the one in psycopg2 be preferred cause it's deeper down the layers, therefore assume to offer better performance ?

Comment: I tend to stick to SQLAlchemy since it gives me a path to higher order ORM functionality. But you don't need to limit yourself; you could mix and match if you want to. (I wouldn't myself, but horses for courses) :)